# fazer sort de um arquivo com múltiplas colunas

Tags: classificação, unix

Olá preciso fazer um sort do meu arquivo, tenho 3 colunas: a primeira seria o cromossomo (1,2,3,4,5..28,W,Z), a segunda seria a posição neste cromossomo e a última seriam valores.

Quando faço o `sort -n`  tenho como resultados os cromossomos sorteados em 10,11,12,13.... mas quero a ordem: 1,2,3...28,W,Z. A segunda coluna gostaria dos valores do menor para o maior. A terceira coluna não importa.

Exemplo do meu input

```
10      247     0.02                      
10      445     0.04                   
10      447     0.08         
11      81     0.04      
11      91     0.01   
1      102     0.03  
1      105     0.05
```

Qual seria o melhor comando?

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar a opção `-V (--version-sort)` do comando `sort` para obter o output desejado.

Do manual:

```
-V, --version-sort
         natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

Assumindo que o teu ficheiro tem nome `ficheiroInput` e contém o seguinte conteúdo

```
A       131     0.01
10      247     0.02                      
10      447     0.04                   
10      445     0.08         
11       81     0.04      
11       91     0.01   
1       105     0.03  
1       102     0.05 
W       202     0.06
```

O comando

```
cat ficheiroInput | sort -k1,1 -V -k2,2
```

irá produzir este output:

```
1       102     0.05 
1       105     0.03  
10      247     0.02                      
10      445     0.08         
10      447     0.04                   
11       81     0.04      
11       91     0.01   
A       131     0.01
W       202     0.06
```

Comment: Muito obrigada Bruno! Eu não tinha tentado a opção -V. É exatamente o que eu precisava!

Comment: De nada. Ainda bem que funcionou!